# computed property based on children within a collection of parents

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a jsbin to illustrate my problem: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xuperezacuha/1/

I have a controller with a property that is a collection of objects (parents), and each parent object has a collection of objects (children).  For example a collection of books where each book has a collection of chapters.

From the jsbin: I have a computed property on my index controller called `allChapters` it does not re compute when a new chapter is added to any of the parents.

How do I base a computed property on a child object being added to any of the parent objects children collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an ember object with a computed property and wrap the children in that object.

```
App.Book = Em.Object.extend({
  chapterLength: Em.computed.alias('chapters.length')
});


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      App.Book.create({name: 'red', chapters: []}),
      App.Book.create({name: 'blue', chapters: []}),
      App.Book.create({name: 'yellow', chapters: []})
    ];
  }
});
```

Then watch the computed property

```
 allChapters: function() {
    _ret = []
    this.get('model').forEach(function(book) {
      book.get('chapters').forEach(function(chapter) {
         _ret.pushObject(chapter);
      })
    })
    return _ret;
  }.property('model.@each.chapterLength'),
```

http://jsbin.com/xuperezacuha/4/edit